# Python Help! Module not working properly. How do I make all values add up?

Tags: python, module

So I'm creating a program on Python and I am having a problem with one of my modules.
This is what it looks like...

def askQuestions(aQ):

```
answer = "nothing"

while answer not in("Yes", "yes", "Y", "y", "YES", "No", "no", "N", "n", "NO"):
    if answer in("Yes", "yes", "Y", "y", "YES"):
        aQ = aQ + Score[0]
    answer = input(Questions[1])
answer = "nothing"

while answer not in("Yes", "yes", "Y", "y", "YES", "No", "no", "N", "n", "NO"):
    if answer in("Yes", "yes", "Y", "y", "YES"):
        aQ = aQ + Score[1]
    answer = input(Questions[2])
answer = "nothing"

while answer not in("Yes", "yes", "Y", "y", "YES", "No", "no", "N", "n", "NO"):
    if answer in("Yes", "yes", "Y", "y", "YES"):
        aQ = aQ + Score[2]
    answer = input(Questions[3])
answer = "nothing"

while answer not in("Yes", "yes", "Y", "y", "YES", "No", "no", "N", "n", "NO"):
    if answer in("Yes", "yes", "Y", "y", "YES"):
        aQ = aQ + Score[3]
    answer = input(Questions[4])
answer = "nothing"


while answer not in("Yes", "yes", "Y", "y", "YES", "No", "no", "N", "n", "NO"):
    if answer in("Yes", "yes", "Y", "y", "YES"):
        aQ = aQ + Score[4]
    answer = input(Questions[5])
answer = "nothing"

while answer not in("Yes", "yes", "Y", "y", "YES", "No", "no", "N", "n", "NO"):
    if answer in("Yes", "yes", "Y", "y", "YES"):
        aQ = aQ + Score[5]
    answer = input(Questions[6])
answer = "nothing"

while answer not in("Yes", "yes", "Y", "y", "YES", "No", "no", "N", "n", "NO"):
    if answer in("Yes", "yes", "Y", "y", "YES"):
        aQ = aQ + Score[6]
    answer = input(Questions[7])
answer = "nothing"


while answer not in("Yes", "yes", "Y", "y", "YES", "No", "no", "N", "n", "NO"):
    if answer in("Yes", "yes", "Y", "y", "YES"):
        aQ = aQ + Score[7]
    answer = input(Questions[8])
answer = "nothing"

while answer not in("Yes", "yes", "Y", "y", "YES", "No", "no", "N", "n", "NO"):
    if answer in("Yes", "yes", "Y", "y", "YES"):
        aQ = aQ + Score[8]
    answer = input(Questions[9])
return aQ
```

It works in the sense of repeating the question when a proper input is not given. But it doesn't add up....so when I get aQ back it is equal to 0, when it shouldn't be. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest initializing aQ at the beginning and printing the value for debugging.

My best guess is that Score[0]...Score[8] don't contain the values you think they do.

It isn't clear what the value aQ is supposed to represent, but unless Score[0]...Score[8] contain unique values it would make sense to just increment by one each time.

Comment: Hey! I tried doing this. And I also tried printing the value of aQ after each while statement and the answer is zero. Score[0]...Score[8]  do contain unique values. What I'm basically trying to do is add up all the scores together (if the player answer "yes", "Yes"...) but at the end when aQ is returned, it is equal to 0. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? I think it may be something to do with setting the answer="nothing"

Comment: Further debugging idea. Print out the value of Score[0]...Score[8] as you go through your code.

You could also try putting all the code here as well as the data.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't quite clear.

I'd paste this as a comment if I could retain the formatting, but here's a suggestion as to how you might possibly reduce repeat code, and also hopefully help you in the process find the source of your problem.

Since your code segments only vary by a numeric value, why not make that a parameter to your function. Something along these lines (not actually run, but you get the idea):

```
def askQuestions(aQ, i):
    answer = "nothing"

    while answer not in("Yes", "yes", "Y", "y", "YES", "No", "no", "N", "n", "NO"):
        if answer in("Yes", "yes", "Y", "y", "YES"):
            aQ = aQ + Score[i]
        answer = input(Questions[i+1])
    return aQ

for n in xrange(0, 9):
    aQ = aQ + askQuestions(aQ, n)
```

Comment: Hey Levon! I just had a quick question about the second part...     for n in xrange(0, 9):
    aQ = aQ + askQuestions(aQ, n)                                               Where do I put it? Like inside the function, or in the main program. As when I put it within the function it said "TypeError: Questions() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)".                                    Sorry if these seem like really simple questions. We have to do a programming assignment at school :)

Comment: @user2930414 the for-loop should definitely not be inside the askQuestion function, but outside it. The indentation level shown should work .. though a full answer would depend on seeing all of the code. I'd take the above as a starting point. Just being able to reduce all of the redundant code to a shorter code segment should make managing it easier hopefully.